# calling qnamaker service from another dialog using node js

Tags: node.js, botframework

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session , next) {
        session.send('Hi Ask me some questions!');
        session.beginDialog('/qna');
    }
]);
bot.dialog('/qna', basicQnAMakerDialog);
```

The issue is that if I type 'hi' it will pass directly the content of the first message..

e.g.

- Me: "HI"
- The Bot: "Hi Ask me some questions!"
- The Bot: "Sorry, I do not understand, you may want to rephrase your question"

But I just want to show `Ask me some question` and then wait for the next question.

And after fetching the results from QnA maker it again prompting with 'hi ask me questions' i want to send that only once

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot without the full bot code. Can you post your code for the `basicQnAMakerDialog`?

Comment: i am also looking same solution can u share if u solve it